# Can we create a reinforcement learning model using the OML4Py feature of the Oracle Autonomous Database?

Tags: oracle-autonomous-db

Can we create a reinforcement learning model using the OML4Py feature of the Oracle Autonomous Database?

I am unable to figure out whether reinforcement learning model can be developed using the OML4Py feature of the Oracle Autonomous Database. Is there support for the same?

Answer (score 0):

OML4Py supports supervised and unsupervised learning techniques through the in-database algorithms. However, OML4Py also supports ***embedded Python execution***, which allows you to use third-party packages by creating custom conda environments on Autonomous Database via OML Notebooks. Such packages could include Reinforcement Learning algorithms.

See OML4Py product documentation for [Installing 3rd-party packages](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4py/2/mlpug/install-3rd-party-packages.html#GUID-217BB2C6-D549-46D3-A110-C1A26152F807) and [Embedded Python Execution](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4py/2/mlpug/embedded-python-execution.html#GUID-AF448E56-B843-4749-979A-F89D359A8728).